# BETWEEN and standard comparison operators Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, between

As I need range of data I am using `BETWEEN` because, as far as I know, this two queries below should be same:

```
select * from table1 where my_date1 - my_date2 between (-1) and (-30);
```

and

```
select * from table1 where my_date1 - my_date2 <= (-1) and my_date1 - my_date2 >= (-30);
```

However when I try it in my script:

```
SELECT  
       a.account_no AS ACCOUNT_NO, 
       a.installment_no AS INSTALLMENT_NO, 
       a.INSTALLMENT_DATE AS INSTALLMENT_DATE 
FROM myTable a 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT 
                        ACCOUNT_NO,
                        MIN(INSTALLMENT_NO) AS INSTALLMENT_NO 
                 FROM myTable  
                 WHERE 
                      ACCOUNT_NO IS NOT NULL 
                      AND INSTALLMENT_NO IS NOT NULL 
                      AND STATUS = 'A'
                      GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NO) b 
     ON A.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO AND A.INSTALLMENT_NO = B.INSTALLMENT_NO
WHERE (TRUNC(INSTALLMENT_DATE) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('12/01/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'))) BETWEEN (-1) AND (-30) -- If I change this
```

I got 0 rows, But when I change

```
WHERE (TRUNC(INSTALLMENT_DATE) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('12/01/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'))) BETWEEN (-1) AND (-30)
```

to

```
WHERE (TRUNC(INSTALLMENT_DATE) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('12/01/2011','DD/MM/YYYY'))) <= (-1) and (TRUNC(INSTALLMENT_DATE) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('12/01/2011','DD/MM/YYYY')))  >= (-30)
```

I get more than 0 rows. I would like to use `BETWEEN` as it is more readable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the syntax for the range used with `BETWEEN` is:

```
WHERE col BETWEEN <smaller_value> AND <larger_value>
```

which is equivalent to

```
WHERE col >= <smaller_value> AND col <= <larger_value>
```

Your current `WHERE` clause is looking for date a date difference *greater* than `-1` and *less* than `-30`.  This will eliminate all the records you are trying to target, and in fact will never be true.  To fix this, correct the range:

```
WHERE (TRUNC(INSTALLMENT_DATE) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('12/01/2011','DD/MM/YYYY')))
    BETWEEN (-30) AND (-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147 says:

> expr1 [NOT] BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
>
> If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty.

Answer (score 1):

BETWEEN is a syntax shortcut that is evaluated as

```
WHERE col >= [smaller_value] AND <= [larger_value]
```

and it is VITAL that the values compared to are presented in that order (small then large) otherwise it will never be satisfied.

---

HOWEVER I never recommend using between for date ranges and suggest, instead, that one always uses  this syntax instead:

```
WHERE col >= [smaller_value] AND < [larger_value]+1
```

This syntax allows accurate filtering of date/time information for any level of time precision.